# cannot deploy war to tomcat with IDE after notebook crash

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea

I'm using intellij IDE, I have maven, spring mvc application, few days ago, my notebook has crashed when I was starting tomcat, I restarted notebook and tried to start my project. It did not work, if I started the project these logs was shown as last:

```
INFO: Deployment of web application directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.62\webapps\manager has finished in 277 ms
jún 16, 2015 8:15:37 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
jún 16, 2015 8:15:37 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder useContextualLobCreation
INFO: HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
[2015-06-16 08:15:39,587] Artifact webapp:war exploded: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
jún 16, 2015 8:15:38 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
jún 16, 2015 8:15:38 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
jún 16, 2015 8:15:39 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
SEVERE: The web application [] registered the JDBC driver [org.postgresql.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
```

But, as I found I can ignore this SEVERE logs, but here it ends, running-project didn't stop, so I could restart the tomcat (not start - it acted like it was running, but it didn't finish)
I reinstalled the idea and downloaded new tomcat, everything was fine, but after several tomcat restarts the problem arises again.
I cannot start tomcat, somethimes the logs looks like those above, but somethimes the last line is:

```
INFO: Deployment of web application directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.62\webapps\manager has finished in 203 ms
```

and starting tomcat stucks.Thanks for any ideas. Btw I've never had a problem like this before my laptop crashed, but since then I can't get rid of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is in what I call invariant state.

Basically

1. remove it via admin
2. manually going to deploying directory and deleting it

You should be able to install it again.

---

If you can not, it depends on why you can not. (Example you run Win Vista and older Tomcat)

Comment: remove it via admin? what exactly do you mean by this? can you more specify the needed steps? thanks.

Comment: tomcat test page ( http://:8080/ ), manager webapp  (http://:8080/manager/html ), host-manager webapp ( http://:8080/host-manager/html )

Comment: I went into /manager/html, then pressed undeploy, restart and nothing ... i can't make it work

Comment: I didn't find how to completely remove an application from context path

Comment: Try to remove your app manually from disk (TOMCAT_HOME\webapps). Remove war file and folder and then restart Tomcat.

Comment: there is no requested war, there are only 4 default folders

Comment: try to move your tomcat into another location (d:\tomcat for example)

Comment: I even downloaded the latest version of tomcat and moved it into another directory, but problem keeps, no idea where could be the problem

Comment: OK guys, I figured it out... the problem was there: I had disabled tomcat localhost log in run config/logs, so I was unable to see the stackTrace logs, but only maven logs, since my build was failing I was unable to see that. I have no 'idea' why idea splitted these logs into two, is it an idea 14 "feature"? But many thanks to both for your willingness, have a nice day.